# MySQL jdbc driver missing wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee

Everything is fine I have installed MySQL driver and added MySQL connector to main MySQL/main added the driver description in standalone.xml but I can't create a datasource when I try to test the connection it gives me this error

```
{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that 
failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc- 
driver.mysql"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.driver-demander.java:/MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
"org.wildfly.data-source.MySqlDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
]
}}}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: i m trying to create a datasource i didn't create any project yet i only want to create the data source i have add the mysql driver to the right directory and created module.xml containing the right code and add the driver code to standalone.xml when i try to create the datasource in the wildfly admin consol on the localhost  everything is fine until i test the connection and get this error
[link](https://imgur.com/a/D6lfdgM) that what i get